# Can anyone explain me the Bracket class in this code?

Tags: python

```
# python3

import sys

class Bracket:

    def __init__(self, bracket_type, position):
        self.bracket_type = bracket_type
        self.position = position

    def match(self, char):
        """Matches given character with the bracket's type."""

        if self.bracket_type == '[' and char == ']':
            return False
        if self.bracket_type == '{' and char == '}':
            return False
        if self.bracket_type == '(' and char == ')':
            return False
        return True


def checker(text):
    stack = []
    for index, char in enumerate(text, start=1):
```

> ```
>         if char in ("[", "(", "{"):            can anyone explain these 
>             stack.append(Bracket(char, index))    two lines as well exactly
> ```

```
        elif char in ("]", ")", "}"):
            if stack:
                return index

            top = stack.pop()
            if not top.match(char):
                return index
    if not stack:
        top = stack.pop()
        return top.position

    return "Success"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    text = sys.stdin.read().strip("\n")
    print(checker(text))
```

in this code, i am struggling with understanding how the bracket class is being called. I mean that i understand how **init** works but i don't understand how the function match in Class bracket works. And how is that impacting the code. I greatly appreciate your help

Comment: You might consider running this code through a debugger.  By inspecting the values of different variables it should quickly become clear what is happening.

Comment: As a side note: If that code is supposed to check the consistency of parentheses, brackets and braces for a given input, then it isn't well implemented at all.

Answer (score 0):

In the code following line will pop one element out of stack which is an instance of the Bracket class, so top becomes that instance and then the `match` method is called within if condition.

```
top = stack.pop()
 if not top.match(char):
```

Comment: thanks for this. can you also tell me about               if char in ("[", "(", "{"):
            stack.append(Bracket(char, index))                               what will this exactly mean in the code?

Answer (score 0):

when you define a function, for example

```
   def match():

          #code
```

you call the function with

```
    match()
```

likewise if you define a class, for example

```
   class bracket:
```

You create an object of the class

```
   brac=bracket()
```

If you pass any argument in the  **init** method. You must add it to the object class. That is

```
    brad=bracket(*args)
```

*args means it can be any argument. The two arguments in your code is bracket_type and position. whose parameters must be passed to the object.
I hope this answer your question about classes

Comment: if char in ("[", "(", "{"):
            stack.append(Bracket(char, index))                               what will this exactly mean in the code?

Answer (score 0):

The for loop below is enumerating through the string you pass to the checker() function.

It returns an index and each character of the string passed to checker().
The reason for the start=1 is not to include the quotes around the string passed to checker().

```
for index, char in enumerate(text, start=1):
```

The conditional below checks for the presence of the characters "[", "(", "{".
If present they are passed as arguments to the Bracket Class. The value returned from the Bracket Class is then appended to the list stack[]

```
if char in ("[", "(", "{"):            
        stack.append(Bracket(char, index))
```

Try adding a print statement after the the for loop like below, and run the code;

```
for index, char in enumerate(text, start=1):
     print(index,char)
     .......
```

I think this will help you understand what it is doing.

```
def __init__(self, bracket_type, position):
        .........
```

In the `Bracket Class`, `bracket_type` is the `char`, and `position` is the `index`